# WPF - How do you set a default value in a dynamically created DataGridComboBox?

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to set a default value for the `ComboBox` within a `DataGrid`, but to no avail. The column I'm looking at is dgProposedDataType and I'm looking at setting it to "Generic" based on the array of values.

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dgDatabase" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="299" Width="819">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridCheckBoxColumn x:Name="dgIsTested" />
        <DataGridComboBoxColumn x:Name="dgProposedDataType" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Window Load Function (as soon as the WPF application opens and loads)

```
private void OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    //Connect to SQL Database
    connObj = new SqlConnection(connection);
    cmdObj = new SqlCommand("SELECT DISTINCT TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME, DATA_TYPE FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS", connObj);
    daAdapObj = new SqlDataAdapter(cmdObj);
    daAdapObj.Fill(dsObj, "Table");
    String[] myArray = { "Generic", "Number", "Date" };

    dgDatabase.ItemsSource = dsObj.Tables["Table"].DefaultView;
    dgProposedDataType.ItemsSource = myArray;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind the `DataGridComboBoxColumn` to a column of the `DataTable`:

```
<DataGridComboBoxColumn x:Name="dgProposedDataType" SelectedItemBinding="{Binding YourColumn}" />
```

You can then set the value of this column for all rows in the `DataTable`:

```
private void OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    //Connect to SQL Database
    connObj = new SqlConnection(connection);
    cmdObj = new SqlCommand("SELECT DISTINCT TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME, DATA_TYPE FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS", connObj);
    daAdapObj = new SqlDataAdapter(cmdObj);
    daAdapObj.Fill(dsObj, "Table");

    String[] myArray = { "Generic", "Number", "Date" };
    dgProposedDataType.ItemsSource = myArray;

    var table = dsObj.Tables["Table"];
    //add a new column to hold the selected value
    table.Columns.Add("YourColumn");
    //set the default value of this column
    foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
        row["YourColumn"] = myArray[0];

    table.Columns["YourColumn"].DefaultValue = myArray[0]; //= Generic

    dgDatabase.ItemsSource = table.DefaultView;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work @mm8 While I do see the values populated, it is initially blank without the default value set.

Comment: @tempidope: See my edit. You actually need to iterate all rows and set the value of the new column.